# Project Android Screen with DroidEx

Tags: android

I am using Mark Murphy's DroidEx tool to project my android device screen; is there a way to supply a skin(e.g. a HTC Hero skin that we use with Android emulator) to DroidEx?

I have also asked this question on the google group for DroidEx project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible, at least with the code as it stands. Support for the now-slumbering DroidEx is handled via the [[cw-android] Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/cw-android). People interested in a software projector for Android may wish to examine [Droid@Screen](http://blog.ribomation.com/2010/01/21/droidscreen/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [android-projector](http://code.google.com/p/android-projector/) utility on Windows.

The projected screen has some flickering problems, due to a very low refresh rate, but it's definitely usable.